# Save a Bitset into a Struct Field

Tags: c++, struct, bitset

I decedied not to use MACROS for the bitwise operations but rather use BitSet. Basically what i am intending to do is, I receive a struct evaluate its bits then appened them to another struct.

I receive a Struct, say:

```
typedef struct{
uint8 status; //!< Status
} MsgStatus;
```

I need to get the status and check each received bit, so i create a bitset of the recevied struct:

```
m_msgBits = new MsgStatus();
bitset<8> msgBits(m_msgBits->status);
// I evaluate the bits
```

Now, after the evaluation I need to appened the received bits to another struct, say:

```
typedef struct{
uint32 status; //!< Status
} MsgOverallStatus;
```

So, what i do is:

```
m_OverallStatus = new MsgOverallStatus();
bitset<16> overallBits(m_OverallStatus->status);
m_OverallStatus.reset(); // 00000000 00000000

//Then append bits in msgBits in overallBits, for example:
overallBits.set(0, msgBits[0]);
overallBits.set(1, msgBits[1]);
overallBits.set(2, msgBits[2]);

//==== HERE WHERE I DUNNO HOW TO DO IT ====
m_OverallStatus->status = overallBits;
```

I want to assign the bits to the struct field, i get this error: cannot convert ‘std::bitset<16u>’ to ‘uint16’ in assignment

I dont want to change the struct field type, so what can I do? I apologize for how silly is my question.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `std::bitset`'s member function `to_ulong`, which returns the bits in the set as an `unsigned long`.